# Sort Array using comparison block

Tags: objective-c

If I have 2 NSMutableArrays and I want to sort one to be in the order of the other, how would I do this with a comparison block? The second array is a list composed of `custom objects` with a property called `name`

```
["Alpha","Gamma","Beta","Delta"]  // Order I want

[CustomObj1,CustomObj2,CustomObj3,CustomObj4]; // Order given
```

Where `CustomObj1.name = "Alpha", CustomObj2.name = "Beta", ... CustomObj4.name = "Gamma"`

Comment: Without the context of your previous question, this one makes no sense because there is no need to sort the 2nd array. You would just use the 1st one. You should update this to indicate that your 2nd array isn't a list of strings but a list of custom objects that has a property value stored in the 1st array.

Comment: @rmaddy goodpoint, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the names in your preferred order:

```
    NSArray *order = @[@"Alpha",@"Gamma",@"Beta",@"Delta"];
```

Here's the array of unsorted items:

```
    NSArray *items = ...;
```

First, make a dictionary that maps each name to its preferred position:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *rankings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:order.count];
    [order enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        rankings[obj] = @(idx);
    }];
```

Then, sort the items by looking up each item's name in the rankings:

```
    NSArray *sortedItems = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        CustomObject *item1 = obj1;
        CustomObject *item2 = obj2;
        return [rankings[item1.name] compare:rankings[item2.name]];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
NSArray * customOrderStrings = @["Alpha","Gamma","Beta","Delta"];
NSArray * givenOrder = [CustomObj1,CustomObj2,CustomObj3,CustomObj4];

NSMutableDictionary * customOrderDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:customOrder.count];

for(CustomObject * co in customOrder)
{
    customOrderDict[co.name] = co;
}

NSMutableArray * customOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:givenOrder.count];

for(NSString * name in customOrderStrings)
{
    [customOrder addObject:customOrderDict[name]];
}
```

Assumptions:
Items in customOrderStrings are unique.
Items in customOrderStrings correspond 1:1 with items in givenOrder.

Comment: Better than my answer.  Derp!